# How to force Excel to use English formats on non-English locale?

Tags: microsoft-excel, locale

I'm using English Windows, English Office but my system locale is Czech. This unfortunately leaks into Excel:

[image]

How do I get rid of this? I want my worksheet to be pure English (US) – all amounts in dollars, number and date formats in en-US, etc.

Comment: What version of excel do you have? Unless 2016, you may have to do it in parts, set language under options, add language pack, make your own custom format for currency, etc.  (2016 ad say it allows office to have complete language todifferent than the os language)

Comment: It's 2016. Do you know how to make it OS-independent, pretty please?